# Como configurar um ambiente de desenvolvimento manualmente

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows, webserver

Estou tentando configurar meu próprio ambiente de desenvolvimento em uma máquina com `Windows 10`.

A ideia seria instalar `Apache + PHP + MySQL`. O problema é que a documentação dos softwares são bastante complicadas para iniciantes como eu e tutoriais não me ajudaram muito.

A maior dificuldade de que encontrei foi em instalar o `MySQL`.

Eu sei que existem diversas opções de ambientes prontos, como o `XAMPP`, e o instalador do `MySQL`, mas a minha intenção é fazer manualmente (linha de comando e arquivos de configuração) para entender como tudo funciona.

Se alguém souber explicar ou indicar um local par ler sobre, me ajudaria muito.

Comment: Já que está em Windows, por que não habilitar o iis e instalar o php manager? Em seguida instale o MySQL.

Comment: Aprender como as coisas funcionam sem usar muletas: excelente iniciativa! Mas vc está usando Windows, então não precisa compilar o negócio. Baixe os instaladores das aplicações e instale uma por uma.

Comment: A ordem de instalação é essa mesmo: _Apache_, depois _PHP_ (que deve te dar a opção de configurar o _Apache já instalado_) depois _MySQL_. Se não me engano, depois de instalar tudo vc vai ter que arrumar alguma configuração no _PHP_ pra ele funcionar com _MySQL, mas é só.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda fazer tudo isso no Linux é mais fácil, não é? Estou pensando em migar.

Comment: Não é exatamente "mais fácil", depende. Se vc conhece _Linux Debian_, por exemplo, pode instalar tudo isso num único comando no terminal. Mas precisa saber ao menos o básico em administração de sistemas _Linux_, caso contrário, continue no Windows mesmo. A decisão de migrar de SO (na minha opinião) deve ter mais a ver com performance. É inegável que _Linux_ sem interface gráfica é melhor em performance (principalmente em uso de memória), mas se vc domina bem o Windows e não tem problema com recursos, continue nele ;)

Comment: Achei esse tutorial aqui:[http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2010/02/22/instalar-apache-php-mysql-no-windows-7-vista-xp/](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/2010/02/22/instalar-apache-php-mysql-no-windows-7-vista-xp/) bastante instrutivo.

Comment: A iniciativa é muito boa, mas se sua versão do Windows não for a pro terá que instalar um wampserver, xamp dentre outros servidores php, mas como você mencionou que quer aprender recomendo instalar o Ubuntu na versão lts e instalar as distros manualmente por linha de comando, aconselho buscar tutoriais independentes para cada aplicação, não é necessário formatar a máquina apenas instale uma vm.

Comment: Fez-me lembrar de meu contato com o php. Em 2002 eu lia as documentação do Windows e, através delas aprendi ASP. Logo depois ouvi falar do php. Tentei instalar mysql, php e apache em um 486 com windows 98. Travou tudo. Fiquei irado. Fui para o centro da cidade para esfriar a cabeça e, ao passar na porta de uma revistaria e vi uma revista chamada Conectiva com um grande pinguim, 4 cd e escrito Linux. Nem sabia dele. Comprei instalei e estou até hoje com o GNU/Linux, mas especificamente o Slackware. Nunca mais mexi com Windows. Boas lembranças!

Comment: Recomendo o Vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/ Além de manter as versões do PHP e MySQL atualizadas facilmente, você terá a experiência de um ambiente web de que precisa

Answer (score 2):

**Primeiro baixe o php**

Em http://windows.php.net/download baixe a versão mais recente do php, baixe o primeiro arquivo que é um zip e extraia em uma pasta, neste exemplo vou extrair em uma pasta com o nome php, que criei em c:

Procure um arquivo com o nome php.ini-development e renomeie para php.ini

**Agora adicione o php nas variaveis de ambiente**

Botão direito em meu computor e escolha propriedades,
na tela que abrir entre em configurações avançadas do sistema, ira abrir outra tela, nela na aba Avançado clique em variaveis de ambiente, na tela que abrir, em variaveis do sistema, selecione Patch e clique em editar, nesta outra tela clique em novo e coloque o C:\php ou o caminho que você extraiu o zip do php, você também pode usar o botão procurar

Para quem estiver usando outra versão do windows, sem ser o 10. Pesquei por "adicionar variavel de ambiente no windows 8 /7/xp"

*Pronto, seu php já esta instalado no windows!*

*Agora só falta o servidor*

No caso de um ambiente de desenvolvimento, você não precisa instalar o apache, as versão atuais do PHP já traz um servido embutido. 
Crie uma pasta www em c: ou qualquer outro lugar, depois navegue até essa pasta pelo cmd e execute o comando php -S localhost:8080

Pronto seu servido já esta rodando! Basta colocar seus arquivos nesta pasta e acessar pelo endereço localhost:8080

Se você não for usar banco de dados, isso já é o suficiente para começar a desenvolver

**Acessando o mysql**

No caso do mysql, não vou colocar nenhum link de passo a passo para instalação, acredito que a maioria que você encontrar no google serve, o que muitos se atrapalham não é na instalação, e sim em acessar o mysql depois da instalação.

Uma coisa é instalar o servidor, outra é instalar um client para acessar o servidor mysql, que seria a interface de acesso.

Apos instalar o mysql eu recomendo usar o heidi SQL, que é muito simples, leve e gratuito
http://www.heidisql.com/

Com o heidi aberto, basta colocar localhost no campo hostname e seu usuario e senha que você escolheu na instalação do mysql nos campos abaixo.

Pronto, seu ambiente de desenvolvimente essencial esta pronto.